# Are cat tracker devices too heavy to put on a cat's collar?

Tags: cats, safety, equipment, gps

I'm looking into tracker devices for my cat. Something that I can put on it's collar to help track it down if it gets lost.

My cat weights about 5kg.  The tracker weighs about 10g. Is this too heavy for the cats neck or will it be OK?

Cat doesn't seem to be showing any discomfort wearing it, but I'd like to be sure

Answer (score 5):

A cat tracker weighing 10 grams is not too heavy for your cat, but cats in general do not like to have objects hanging around their neck.

I think it is better to get your cat microchipped to avoid it being lost, but this is probably something you have done.

If your cat does spend his/her time in your garden, you will probably not need to use the tracker there, but if you bring the cat with you to unknown areas, using it might be a good idea.

Cats of normal size have no problems in carrying 50 grams around the neck for the whole day, but they will need some time to get used to it dangling around the neck, and they might get scared at first.

Answer (score 4):

The main concern here should not be the weight, but attachment.

When putting a collar on a cat, one should make sure to get one that has a safety unlock feature that opens the collar by weight, and that it is properly set for the cats weight.

Collars without this feature pose a significant danger, as the collar might get caught on a fence or strong branch of a bush while climbing. If the cat is unable to free itself, there is a significant risk of strangulation.

These collars do tend to come off now and then in non-emergency situations, but one that has a tracker attached to it will be recoverable.